# How to get references to ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment which contains two kinds of child views:

```
(1) A View which contains an image from the internet.
(2) A WebView which pulls information from the server.
```

Basically, all the list items in the listview contains web data retrieving. So when the ListFragment becomes invisible all pending requests must be canceled.

What I am trying to do is overriding the

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
```

method in ListFragment.

However I don't know how to get references to the list item views within ListFragment.

The only way I can come up with is storing the list items in the adapter. Then I call ListFragment.getListView.getAdapter then retrieve the references to the list items. But I am not sure if this is a good practice to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: it depends on how you keep track of your pending requests. Normally, they can be managed inside the adapter, so accessing and doing it in adapter is fine. Why do you rely on `setUserVisibleHint` instead of `onStop` to detect when fragment becomes non-visible ? (although it should work too)

Comment: @kiruwka Thanks that's a good point. setUserVisibleHint() seems don't make sense here.